# Laravel 5.6 database sessions not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session

My app has been working with file-based sessions just fine. However, after switching to the database driver my sessions stopped working. This is exactly what happens:

1. The user opens the login page (a session gets created in the `sessions` table with `user_id = NULL`)
2. The user fills in his\her login credentials and submits the form (the session in the database acquires a `user_id = 1`)
3. The system tries to redirect the user to a post-login page, however by that time the session has been terminated (the session has `user_id = NULL`)

To switch to the database driver I only did the following (the app was already working with file-based sessions):

#### Created the sessions table using:

- `php artisan session:table`
- `composer dump-autoload`
- `php artisan migrate`

#### Configured `config/sessions.php` as follows:

- `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database')`
- `'connection' => 'mysql'`
- `'table' => 'sessions'`
- `'domain' => 'test.local'`

#### My .env file:

- `DB_CONNECTION=mysql`
- `SESSION_DRIVER=database`

#### routes.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'test.local', 'middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::group(['domain' => 'test.local', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
        // post-login routes...
    }

    // show the login form
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLogin');

    // submit the login form
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@submitLogin');
}
```

Am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated.